# Difference Normal Implies Conditional Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $X-Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
I want to show $X|Y \sim N(Y+\mu, \sigma^2)$ in the sense that 
$$
E(g(X)|Y) = \int g(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp(-(x-(Y+\mu))^2/2\sigma^2)dx
$$
for every measurable function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt**

I thought I could proceed as follows. Set $h(z)=g(z)+Y$.
\begin{align}
E(g(X)|Y) 
&= E(g(X-Y+Y)|Y) \\
&= E(h(X-Y)|Y) \\
&=
\label{1}\tag{1}
\int h(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp(-(z-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2)dz \\
&=
\int g(z+Y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp(-(z-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2)dz \\
&=
\int g(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp(-(x-(\mu+Y))^2/2\sigma^2)dx 
\end{align}
where the last line is a change of variable.

However, \eqref{1} doesn't seem correct unless $X-Y$ is independent from $Y$.

**Context**

Brownian motion with $W_0 = 0$, $W_{t} - W_{s} \sim N(0,t-s)$ when $0 \leq s \leq t$, $W_{t} - W_{s}$ independent from $W_{t'} - W_{s'}$ when $0 \leq s < t \leq s' < t'$. I'd like to argue that $W_t | W_s \sim N(W_s,\sigma^2)$ with the meaning above.

Do I need to use independent increments somehow? If so, how?

Edit: I came up with this before seeing @Marcus M 's answer; it's the same I think:

Would it be okay to argue as follows? $W_t - W_s$ is independent from $W_s-W_0 = W_s$, so $E(h(W_t-W_s)|W_s) = E(h(W_t-W_s)|W_s-W_0) = E(h(W_t-W_s))$. I think this even works if $W_0$ is a non-zero constant because conditioning on $W_s-W_0$ would still be equivalent to conditioning on $W_s$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, line $(1)$ is only true if $X - Y$ is independent of $Y$.  In the Brownian motion case, you're all good since you know $W_t - W_s$ is independent of $W_s$.

To see that your first statement isn't true in general, note that if you take $Y \sim N(0,1)$ and $X = 2Y$ then $X - Y = Y$ so $E[g(X)|Y] = g(X)$ since $X$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y)$ (where $\sigma(Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which $Y$ is measurable.)